# It is a question about the features of an object code

Tags: oop, object, compiler-construction

I knew recently that an object file may contain placeholders and offsets not found in the machine code of the whole program.....
I wantto know what are the placeholders and the offsets.
And thanks in advance.

Comment: You mean relocations? Which operating system are you interested in?

Comment: I am sorry for answering you late , i am using windows 7.